# Ruby PTY spawn left pseudoterminal device file opened

Tags: ruby, pty

I am running into a problem using the Ruby PTY gem. It seems that after I spawn a process using PTY, it will left with opened device file /dev/ptmx

Example:

```
require 'pty'
PTY.spawn('ls') do |r,w,pid|
  Process.kill(9, pid)
  Process.wait(pid)
end
```

For each spawn above, I am left with:

```
ruby      72578  user  10u      CHR               15,8       0t0      572 /dev/ptmx
ruby      72578  user  11u      CHR               15,8       0t0      572 /dev/ptmx
```

The files eventually get closed when the program finishes but my server is not designed to terminate.

I thought using the "PTY.spawn ... do" block will ensure PTY clean up everything. But I was wrong. Is there a proper way to terminate PTY?

Comment: Just a note that the problem will not happen if you 1) do not kill the underlying process, or 2) manually `close` the read and write handles in the block.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug (or feature?) of `spawn`. It only seems to happen if you kill the underlying process prematurely.

However this problem is easy to get around by closing the file handles yourself. This can be accomplished transparently like this:

```
def PTY.spawn_safe(command, &block)
  PTY.spawn(command) do |r,w,pid|
    yield r,w,pid
    w.close
    r.close
  end
end

# No more dangling file handles
PTY.spawn_safe('ls') do |r,w,pid|
  Process.kill(9, pid)
  Process.wait(pid)
end
```